# SQL Building a string to find decimal fields exceeding certain amounts

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

NOTICE: after reading the comments i realized my question is probably too confusing. So, I'm trying again:

I'm trying to write a generic sql query to find all decimal fields in my database with a value > 1000000 (see example below)

For some reason, if I just try to add the Select-queries together, i get an error because of the `>` character in the `where ['+c.name+'] > 1000000` condition.

My goal is to find the proper way of writing this generic script.

I already found a workaround:
By adding `for xml path('')` to the end of the select statement, that generates the new query, I can bypass the error. But this brings the problem that any character with an html-counterpart gets replaced. (e.g. `>` is turned into `&gt;` which i have to revert again (as seen at the end of my example)

working workaround (as long as there aren't any new special characters added)

```sql
declare @qry nvarchar(max);

set @qry = (
select  'if exists(select [' + c.name + '] from [' + t.name + '] where ['+c.name+'] > 1000000) select ''['+t.name+'].['+c.name+']'' , count(*) from [' + t.name + '] where ['+c.name+'] > 1000000;'
from sys.all_columns c
    inner join sys.tables t on t.object_id = c.object_id
where c.system_type_id = 106
for xml path(''));
set @qry = REPLACE(@qry, '&gt;', '>')
set @qry = REPLACE(@qry, '&amp;', '&')
select @qry
exec sp_executesql @qry
```

Comment: Do you suppose you could provide even more extensive sample data? The problem is, at least to me, somewhat unclear. Tip: The best practice when assembling object names into dynamic SQL statements is to use [`QuoteName()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/quotename-transact-sql) to avoid problems with odd names, e.g. `New Table` with a space or reserved words like `From`.

Comment: `c.name` seems to contain some alphanumeric thing (like: `Company Name A$LOGPJ Draft & Letter Of Cred$150cb219-940b-42e8-8d84-27e357e14165`), How can that be `> 1000000` ??

Comment: @Luuk the c.name contains the name of the column. I'm building a generic scrip that checks all the decimal fields, it will work on any database with decimal fields and is not the issue of my question.

Answer (score -1):

You can try to first build the XML, and then select from the XML. This will *convert* the `&gt;` back to '>' (and all other stuff like that).

```
declare @qry xml;
declare @queries nvarchar(max);
declare @new xml;

set @qry = (
select 'if exists(select [' + c.name + '] from [' + t.name + '] where ['+c.name+'] > 1000000) select ''['+t.name+'].['+c.name+']'' , count(*) from [' + t.name + '] where ['+c.name+'] > 1000000;'
from sys.all_columns c
    inner join sys.tables t on t.object_id = c.object_id
where c.system_type_id = 106
for xml path(''));

set @new = (select top 1 @qry  for xml path('foo'),root('bar'));
select @new.value('/bar[1]/foo[1]','nvarchar(max)');
```